# specific swap partitions for multiple debian instances in a single computer

Tags: debian, dual-boot, fstab, swap

I'm trying to setup a computer with three debian instances (wheezy, jessie and sid), I've created `/` and `swap` partitions for each debian instance, during the installation I did specify which swap partition to use for each instance, and I did verify that the other partitions were configured as "do not use this partition", but when running jessie I see the three swap partitions are active

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda10                              partition   7812092 0   -1
/dev/sda12                              partition   7812092 0   -2
/dev/sda8                               partition   8191996 0   -3
```

my `/etc/fstab` file only refers to one of them

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
UUID=199fd69d-285e-4fec-9d5d-498d4d4b92a2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=562B-713C  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda12 during installation
UUID=7e958357-a446-4a32-7c06-81f6751fdab6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

I know I can `swapoff` the swap partitions corresponding to the other debian instances, and it could be done in a `@reboot` entry of cron, but I don't like that, to prevent data loss I would prefer them not to be touched at all. Then the question is: how do I tell debian not to use some specific swap partition?

**EDIT 1**

could this be a consequence of udev configuration?

**EDIT 2**

contents of my `/etc/mtab` file are the following

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1007169,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1614768k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/199fd69d-285e-4fec-9d5d-498d4d4b92a2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/116 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=807384k,mode=700,uid=116,gid=123 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=807384k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
```

Comment: Why not use the same swap partition for all 3?

Comment: I want them to be as functional as possible, and in [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Swap) page it says "If you intend to use Hibernate you should ensure that your Debian installation has access to a swap partition or file that is NOT shared with another instance of GNU/Linux." In practice I've using shared swap partitions for some time without major trouble, but now I'm trying to improve my system a little.

Comment: In that case you want to remove the swap activator from the run level.

Comment: Weird. A Linux installation should definitely not touch any partition that isn't explicitly listed. Please check that the swap partitions have different UUIDs: run `blkid /dev/sda8 /dev/sda10 /dev/sda12`. If you replace the UUID by `/dev/sda8`, does it change anything?

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the answer, the partitions do have different UUID, and I've tried using `/dev/sda12` instead of the UUID in the fstab file, but I get the same result.

Comment: @eyoung100, I did a fast search for "swap activator" but I can't find anything useful. Can you please give me some link or hint on where to read about this kind of solution?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/mtab` if you have one?  I'll explain what the swap activator is as soon as I find it in the runlevel list.

Comment: I added an ubuntu (14.04) installation to the same machine and doesn't have this problem, the fstab file looks the same.

Answer (score -1):

This monstrous UUIDs for swap, who needs it? Here's my fstab swap partitions:

```
/dev/sda1              none       swap  sw         0 0
/dev/sdb1              none       swap  sw         0 0
```

... not to difficult to see what's happening.

Comment: You have two entries in `fstab`, and I presume we're supposed to guess your system uses two swap partitions. But boclodoa only has one entry and still his system uses three partitions. What is happening on boclodoa's system then? If you can see it, spell it out for us.

Comment: No guessing, yes, two swaps.  I'm just pointing out that dumping the UUIDs and going to '/dev' entries would sure make it easier to know what's happening.